# Path changed after pre-compiling assets in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

I am using Ruby on rails - Heroku. I wanted to upload a file to server. So I pre-compiled the assets , and pushed the updates to server. But the path of all image files got changed and images are looking broken. I want to revert it back, what should I do?

Comment: You may have to give us more info to help you. Can you expand on "the path of all image files got changed" - was that something else you did, or are you saying that the act of pre-compiling somehow changed image paths? which images are looking broken? can you show us the template-code that creates those urls? wheat it should be and what it is instead?

Comment: Till yesterday it was working properly, I did following and its giving error.
I wanted an image to be changed on server, So I did following steps Copied the image to local /app/assets/images
Asset complied on local with:bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Image committed on Git
Executed the command to compile on production : bundle exec rake assets:precompile ENV=production
Executed command on Heroku bash
Open URL 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/tmp/X/X.jpeg")(In log)
I guess precompiled paths of S3 images are mismatching , resulting into routing error

Comment: Hi cool, this is really useful info. I forgot to say: the formatting in comments is really awful - makes it hard to read. Could you please edit your question and put it there? that was we can see the steps easier.

Comment: I notice one thing that I would expect to have happened: between the step "committed on Git" and the step "Executed the command to compile on production" - there is not a step "deployed from git to production". Do you have your system set up so that it automatically deploys from git to production or did you miss that step? (just checking all the possibilities)